# Xcode Swift change data uitableview on sidemenu

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm new on iOS Swift!
I want to make application login and logout then I use this example to start, I want to change or remove or add Item4(Logout) in sidemenu after I click Login button on First Controller.

I try many way but I can't do it

Source: https://github.com/haorui/SwiftSideMenu

[image: Screenshot One][image: Screenshot Two]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update data using notification

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.sidePanelController.showCenterPanelAnimated(true)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadData", object: nil, userInfo: ["Index":indexPath.row])

}
```